# Sendgrid Unauthenticated senders not allowed error php, zf2

Tags: zend-framework2, sendmail, sendgrid

I have integrate Sendgrid for my Zend Framework 2 Application using STMP API and i have used Zend Transport for but I get a error

"Caught exception: Cannot receive from specified address : Unauthenticated senders not allowed"

```
 $request = $this->getRequest();
    //$form = new Add();
    // $product = new Product();
    $username = 'XXX';
    $password ='XXXX';
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){ // If it's ajax call
        $email = $request->getPost('email_add');
        $message = $request->getPost('message');
        try{
            $message = new Message();
            $message->addTo('jainudeenf007@gmail.com')
                ->addFrom('fawazj@digitalglare.com.au')
                ->setSubject('Greetings and Salutations!')
                ->setBody("Sorry, I'm going to be late today!");
            $transport = new SmtpTransport();
            $options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
                'name'              => 'sendgrid.com',
                'host'              => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
                'port'              => 587, // Notice port change for TLS is 587
                'connection_class'  => 'smtp',
                'connection_config' => array(
                    'auth' => 'login',
                    'username' => 'XXXXXX',
                    'password' => 'XXXXXX',
                    'ssl'      => 'tls'
                ),
            ));
            $transport->setOptions($options);
            $transport->send($message);
            exit;
        }catch (\Exception $ex){
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $ex->getMessage(), "\n";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sendgrid has an api and this api is implemented by [SlmMail](http://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmMail) (disclaimer: I am the author of SlmMail). Using that API is easier to use than using the old SMTP protocol.

I am not sure how to exactly configure the SMTP options, but previously we worked with the Google SMTP servers and it required this configuration:

```
'name' => 'gmail.com',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'connection_class'  => 'login',
'connection_config' => array(
    'ssl'      => 'tls',
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
),
```

This is slightly different than yours ("class" is "login", there is no "auth" option). Check also the [documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mail.smtp.options.html#zend-mail-smtp-options) where all SMTP options are specified.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the SimMail option, you can try using Zend's mail module as described in our documentation: http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/zend.html

One other option is our Web API, for which we have a PHP library here: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

connection_class plain should work

```
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;

            $transport = new SmtpTransport();
            $options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
                'name'              => $name,
                'host'              => $host,
                'port'              => 587,
                'connection_class'  => 'plain',
                'connection_config' => array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                ),
            ));
            $transport->setOptions($options);
            $transport->send($mail);
```